# Why I can't find by id XML image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    Button buttonForCP;
    ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonForCP =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonForCP);
        img = findViewById(R.drawable.ic_img);//this problem 
                                    // ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
        buttonForCP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonForCP.setBackground(img);
        }
    });
}
```

for some reason can not read xml image the compiler writes "Expected resource of type id"
I googled nothing found help please

Comment: You can also provide your `activity_main.xml file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `backButtonZer` is a `Button`, you need to replace `R.drawable.ic_img` with `R.id.backButtonZer`

```
backButtonZer = findViewById(R.id.backButtonZer);
```

---

Update

To set background to the `Button` you can use `setBackgroundResource` method:

```
buttonForCP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        buttonForCP.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_img);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already tried, but I made another mistake

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'ic_backbuttonzer'

Comment: can you add to your question the content of `your activity_main.xml` file?

Comment: 'ic_backbuttonzer' Sounds as a drawable file too. You must add the id you had for the item in your xml. 
<Button
        android:id="@+id/nameYouWant"

Comment: `buttonForCP.setBackground(img);` you can't do like this, it is impossible to use a `ImageView` as background.

Comment: I'm sorry, but everything is fine with Activity main

Comment: problem in mainActivity.java

Comment: see my updated answer. " I'm sorry, but everything is fine with Activity main" what do you mean?

Comment: @ОрестТретяк can you share `.xml` code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work because **findViewById** finds the view by id inside your inflated layout. But you are trying to find drawable resource id and assign it to an ImageView object which makes no sense at all.

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.drawable.ic_img);
```

Also with this code, you are tying to set an ImageView as a button background, which makes no sense too. You can set an image/resource/drawable as a background. Not an ImageView.

```
buttonForCP.setBackground(img);
```

There are lots if missing points in your question, but maybe you can try something like that:

```
buttonForCP.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_img);
```